# I am working on ExtentReports, so i wanted to add its dependencies to pom.xml. But adding dependencies creating error in pom.xml

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium, selenium-extent-report

I am working on ExtentReports, so i wanted to add its dependencies to pom.xml. But adding dependencies creating error in pom.xml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfM8F.png)

Comment: <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.9</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Might be worth your while to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to better explain your question so users are able to help

Comment: please be more specific and paste your error as text

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.